# How to determine if an internal transaction creates a new contract?

Tags: internal-transactions, create

I'm working on programmatically analyzing smart contracts and I need a way to determine if an internal transaction is creating a new contract. Can this be done by looking at the event logs? Anyone know how to approach this?

example: https://etherscan.io/txsInternal?block=4752011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)`